# Retornando lista com propriedade de varias entidades

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Em minha aplicação tenho algumas entidades e a partir de algumas informa coes de cada uma preciso realizar uma consulta no banco de dados e exibir estas informa coes em um *grid*. Estou trabalhando com ASP.Net MVC 4 e minha aplicação esta dividida em camadas: VO, BO, DO

Vou tentar passar um exemplo mais resumido da dificuldade que estou tendo. Vejam as entidades abaixo:

```
    class Cliente
{
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public string NomeCliente { get; set; }
}

class Usuario
{
    public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }
}

class ChamadoTecnicoStatus
{
    public int IdChamadoTecnicoStatus { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoChamadoTecnicoStatus { get; set; }
}

class ChamadoTecnico
{
    public int IdChamadoTecnico { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataChamadoTecnico { get; set; }
    public int IdChamadoTecnicoStatus { get; set; }
    public string InformacaoChamadoTecnico { get; set; }
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
}
```

O que eu vou precisar é fazer um select no banco e trazer as informa coes como abaixo:

```
IdChamadoTecnico | DataChamadoTecnico | DescricaoChamadoTecnicoStatus | InformacaoChamadoTecnico | NomeCliente | NomeUsuario
```

Acredito que poderia facilmente resolver isso  se eu retornar para minha camada de apresentação um `DataTable` mas era exatamente isso que eu não queria fazer. Queria que meu método me retornasse apenas um `List<objeto>` só que desta maneira eu teria que ter esta entidade:

```
    class EntidadeParaListaDeChamadosTecnicos
{
    public int IdChamadoTecnico { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataChamadoTecnico { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoChamadoTecnicoStatus { get; set; }
    public string InformacaoChamadoTecnico { get; set; }
    public string NomeCliente { get; set; }
    public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }
}
```

E isso eu acredito totalmente não ser recomendado fazer.

Qual a melhor pratica? Estou procurando algum *pattern* pela internet mas atá agora não achei nada.

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Por favor, use português formal, acentuando tudo que puder e souber. Seu teclado tem `ç` e `~`, não?

Comment: @Marcelo Você está usando Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma seria realmente criar uma ModelView (MV) e então seu Controller popular a mesma com os dados que serão exibidos na sua View